# loading divs that only have data in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has some divs. I show images on these divs. Sometimes, the some divs may be emtpy and some may have values.

Clicking on a div, I show another div with an image. And, clicking on the div with images, should bring me back to the original location. I know this is little complicated. .group css class contain bunch of divs. I only want to show the divs that have value. Below code kinda works but since I am doing this ( $('.group').show();), it shows all the divs and the display of the full images all spread around. Is there a way to purge the emtpy divs so that only divs with images show and the others are purged. thank you.

```
  $(function () {
             $('#individual').click(function () {
             $('.aggregate').hide();
             $('#aggregate').show();
             });

                 $('#aggregate').click(function () {
                    $('#aggregate').hide();
                    $('.group').show();
              });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
$(function () {
             $('#individual').click(function () {
             $('.aggregate').hide();
             $('#aggregate').show();
             });

                 $('#aggregate').click(function () {
                    $('#aggregate').hide();
                    $('.group').each(function(){
                       if($(this).html()!='')
                          $(this).show();
                    });
              });
     });
```